# How can I repair crumbling tile sealant?

Tags: sealing

About a year ago, we hired a worker to tile my kitchen : I don't know how he worked, I wasn't there. The result seemed good enough.

However, today, in some places, the sealant seems to be crumbling : we occasionally find bits about 1 cm long.

What causes that, and what can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

Let me see if I understand: Your kitchen wall is covered with ceramic tiles and the "sealant" is actually grouting between the tiles, right, and now grouting is falling off? If this is the case my first guess is that grouting mass was old (wasn't used before expiration date).There could be some other reasons like poor workmanship etc. On of this is really a big deal, I mean it's not anything serious. What you should do is clear with some sharp tool existing grouting and apply new one. Material is not expensive, and you can do it on your own, because it doesn't require any special skill, just follow the manual.

Comment: Sorry if it was a bit difficult to understand, English is not my mother language. I'll try what you are suggesting, seems reasonable.

Comment: Don't worry, English isn't my native either, and this are technical terms. That’s why picture is appreciated in these situations.